# What effect has $ in a Java class name

Tags: java, class, gson

I recently saw the source code of the Google library Gson and saw something really strange (IMO). In the com.google.gson.internal package there are 2 classes which do begin with a "$".

For example

```
public final class $Gson$Types { ... }
```

Does the dollar sign has a effect to development or is it just to say to outside developers something like "please don't use cause it is a internal class"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use any currency sign or continuation character in an identifier.

By using $, it suggests it is generated e.g. generated by the build, or for internal use only.

[Uses for special characters in Java code](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/uses-for-special-characters-in-java-code.html)

[Hidden code](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-code.html)

It only causes a problem if you have conflicts with generated classes e.g.

```
class A {
     class B {
     }
}
class A$B {
}
```

reports

```
error: duplicate class: A.B
```

Compiler generated classes do not start with a `$` which may be reason this as done.

On Windows 7, the special characters which can appear in a Class are

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    for (char ch = 0; ch < Character.MAX_VALUE; ch++) {
        if (Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(ch) && !Character.isLetter(ch))
            System.out.println("interface " + ch + " { }");
    }
}

interface $ { }
interface _ { }
interface ¢ { }
interface £ { }
interface ¤ { }
interface ¥ { }
interface € { }
```

Other special characters are allows by Java, but not supported as file names.  This may depend on the OS and possibly the language.

Comment: I don't think you can use "any" currency sign. From the JLS: "The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems." I doubt that a Euro sign would be valid, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet The important word is *include*. Most currency signs also qualify, including the € (euro) sign.

Comment: Euro is allowed, but it is one of the few which are. Tried the all on Windows 7. ;)

Comment: This is really interesting. I'm still puzzled cause I don't see why they did this. I will assume that the dollar sign hints that these classes are generated but still I checked the whole svn repo but didn't see anything which could generate these classes. But even if they are generated, why would someone commit them into the version control system?

Answer (score 1):

From the compiler/runtime's perspective, it's just a character that forms part of the name, like the `G` or the `s`.  It doesn't have any particular semantic meaning.

However, the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) does hint that you should avoid using the `$` character yourself in identifiers:

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> ...
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters `A`-`Z` (`\u0041`-`\u005a`), and a-z (`\u0061`-`\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`) and dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`). The `$` character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is very wrong, google shouldn't have done that. The $ sign is specifically reserved as a delimiter in nested classes. Many code, including JDK, depends on this convention (which is observed by almost everybody). google's naughty naming practice would break these codes.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?